# Thymeleaf+Spring, isAuthenticated()/hasRole() not working

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a problem with isAuthenticated() method. It seems it always return  false no matter if the user is logged in or not. Also after calling this method nothing is shown to the end of the html code. In this example:

```
aaa
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    This content is only shown to authenticated users.
</div>
bbb
ccc
```

only `aaa` is shown.

```
Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span>
Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span>
```

^this code works perfectly, so there should not be a problem with `sec:` (I guess)

My Thymeleaf config class:

```
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/static/css/");

    }
}
```

And maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i solved this problem. This is from : https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity

`Requirements (3.0.x)
Spring Framework version 3.0.x to 4.3.x
Spring Security version 3.0.x to 4.2.x`

I was using Spring 5.0.0 - with Spring 4.3.13 and Spring Security 4.2.3 everything works fine.

Comment: I was facing simillar issue. Was using spring boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE with thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4. Issue got fixed after changing it to thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5

Answer (score 2):

```
Change your file pom.xml, and add this these dependencies:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Now in your html file add:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

that is all 


    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
        Text visible only to authenticated users.
    </div>
```